# How to print only alphanumeric line from my file?

Tags: linux, text-processing

---

Here is my file .From this file i need to print only alphanumeric line using linux/unix commands?

```
1234567890 
1234567890 
123456789X 
0974385495
```

Expected Output:

```
123456789X
```

Obtained output by the following command:

```
$ tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < distinct_file.txt

12345678901234567890123456789X0974385495
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This filter gives all lines which has at least one alpha charater:

```
grep '[[:alpha:]]' distinct_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `grep`: do an OR-ing (`|`) of any alphabetic (`[:alpha:]`), followed anytime later by any digit (`[:digit:]`), and vice versa:

```
grep -E '[[:alpha:]].*[[:digit:]]|[[:digit:]].*[[:alpha:]]'
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
1234567890
1234567890
123456789X
0974385495

% grep -E '[[:alpha:]].*[[:digit:]]|[[:digit:]].*[[:alpha:]]' file.txt 
123456789X
```

Comment: Or `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z]\d|\d[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

Comment: Are you sure the you want the `.`s in your regex?

Comment: @SteveBennett `*` after `.` makes that optional...

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know why you'd want to match any random character. So you'd match 'F-9' or '5 +#$%*&A', which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the lines that contain at least one digit and at least one alphabetical character, then:

```
< file grep '[[:digit:]]' | grep '[[:alpha:]]'
```

If, in addition you want that all the characters are alnums, you can pipe the above to `grep -v '[^[:alnum:]]'` (remove the lines (`-v`) that contain at least one non-alnum), or in one `grep` command:

```
< file grep -xe '[[:alnum:]]*[[:digit:]][[:alnum:]]*[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*' \
             -e '[[:alnum:]]*[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*[[:digit:]][[:alnum:]]*'
```